# Asp.Net Core Remote validation attribute not making call

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2

I have set the Remote attribute to validate that my username is Unique but when I debug it's not firing.   What am I messing up?

In my View Model here is the attribute and property:

```
[Required]
[Remote("VerifyUsername", "Account")]
public string Username { get; set; }
```

In my form my form attribute is:

```
<input asp-for="Username" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Username" />
<span asp-validation-for="Username"></span>
```

And in my controller I have tried:

```
public JsonResult VerifyUsername(string username)
{
    if (!_user.UsernameUnique(username))
    {
        return Json($"{username} is already in use.");
    }

    return Json(true);
}
```

And the method format:

```
[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
public IActionResult VerifyUsername(string username)
{
    if (!_user.UsernameUnique(username))
    {
        return Json($" {username} is already in use.");
    }

    return Json(true);
}
```

I enter a usernam and click around and try tabbing... nothing gets the remote validation to fire.  Anyone see what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

So I found it... kind of a facepalm.   I was using another library that was loading another version of jquery.  I was not getting an error though so that was weird.  I removed that script reference for that other version of jquery and so it just had the current version and it all worked.